# Question about NullExceptionError in C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, compiler-errors

See the below code for a testing of a function:

```
 List<Square> tempArr = new List<Square>();
 Coin tempCoin = new Coin(eCoinType.White);
 Square tempMove = new Square(1, eColumn.A, tempCoin);
 tempArr.Add(tempMove);
 m_OtheloGame.isLegalMove(tempMove, ref tempArr);
```

The compiler painted "tempArr" in the last line with NullExceptionError.

I don't understand why because I've already allocated tempArr in the first line so it can't be a null.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "The compiler painted tempArr"?

Comment: Yes I meant it was underlined with red color

Comment: What is the output when you try to compile it?

Comment: Can you post the detail of the exception?  The callstack probably has more in it than we're seeing in the question.

Comment: Do you *really* need to pass `tempArr` by reference?

Comment: @Jon: Hey Jon! You are everywhere ;-) .I tried to refactor the code you saw in previous question we discussed.As a reminder started with out parameter so tried to change it to ref with a couple of changes..

Comment: @Mulder: I think you need to take a step back and think about what you're really trying to do. Also make absolutely sure you understand what ref and out mean. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html for a detailed article.

Answer (score 0):

What does isLegalMove() method do, since tempArr passed in as ref it's possible that it could be changed to reference a null

Answer (score 0):

Look for troubles inside the `isLegalMove` method.
Also, go to Debug/Exceptions and enable Common Language Runtime Exceptions on both columns: Thrown and User-unhandled. Then run again, you should be notified where the actual error occurs inside the `isLegalMove` method.